# NoSuchMethodError On Completable RXJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

Good day all, am trying to use RxJava2 in the following code but i keep getting the following java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method.

Here is my code:

```
 userAccount.startUserSession(String.valueOf(id), authkey)     

.andThen(userAccount.getUser())         

    .map(userAccount -> {     userAccount.setToken(accessToken);       
               return userAccount;
             })            

    .flatMapCompletable(userAccount -> userAccount.update(userAccount))

    .subscribe(() ->{},

    throwable -> {});
```

This is the UserAccount:

```
               @Override
                public Completable startUserSession(String clientId, String key) {

                       return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {

                               registerAccount(clientId, key);

                               return null;

                       });
                }


        @Override
                     public Observable<UserAccount> getUser() {          


        return Observable.create(this::getAvailableAccounts)       

              .flatMap(Observable::fromArray)         

         .map(this::getUserAccount);

      }


        private void getAvailableAccounts(Emitter<Account[]> emitter) {       

         try {                     
        emitter.onNext(getAccountsByType());                    
        emitter.onComplete();             
         } catch (NoSuchElementException throwable){                     emitter.onError(throwable);                
         }             
        }                          

        private void registerAccount(String clientId,String key)throws Exception{            

                      
    if (getAccountsByType().length > 0) {                 
            //do something like throw exception                
         }                 
        Account account = new Account(key, accountType);       
          accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);        
        accountManager.setUserData(account, CLIENT_KEY_ID, clientId);       
     accountManager.setUserData(account, CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_KEY, key);             
            ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, Authority, 1);      
       ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, Authority, true);      
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, Authority, new Bundle(), 1);

    } 

        @Override             
        public Completable update(UserAccount userAccount) {         


         return Completable.create(completableEmitter -> {        
                 updateUserAccount(userAccount, completableEmitter);       

         });

      private void updateUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount,CompletableEmitter completableEmitter) {        


        try {              
        updateAccount(userAccount);         

        completableEmitter.onComplete();         

        } catch (AccountException uax) {           

         completableEmitter.onError(uax);             

          }        
     }

        private void updateAccount(UserAccount userAccount)throws AccountException {          

                            
        Account account = getAccountsByType()[0];         

        UserAccount mainUser = getUserAccount(account);          

        if(mainUser.getUserId().equals(userAccount.getUserId())) {        
                 accountManager.setUserData(account, 
CLIENT_AUNTHENTICATION_TOKEN, userAccount.getToken());           

         } else {           

         // do something like throw an exception                
         }

        }        
                  
        private UserAccount getUserAccount(Account account) {          


         UserAccount userAccount = new
        UserAccount(accountManager.getUserData(account, CLIENT_KEY));     

        String token = accountManager.getUserData(account, CLIENT_TOKEN);     

        if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {       
              userAccount.setToken(token);        

         }         

        return userAccount;

        }
```

the methods both return a completable apart from userAccount.getuser() which returns an Observable. Am a bit confused what could be triggering it. Any Ideas.

This is my error log:

```
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method com_data_useraccount_UserAccountManager$$Lambda$1_lambda$startUserSession$0(Lcom/data/useraccount/UserAccountManager;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/data/useraccount/UserAccountManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.data.useraccount.UserAccountManager' appears in /data/app/com.example-1/base.apk)

        at com.data.useraccount.UserAccountManager$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)

        at
     io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromCallable.subscribeActual(CompletableFromCallable.java:35)

      at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1592)

    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableToObservable.subscribeActual(CompletableToObservable.java:29)

        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)

    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDelaySubscriptionOther.subscribeActual(ObservableDelaySubscriptionOther.java:94)

    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)

    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:32)

    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)

     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMapCompletableCompletable.subscribeActual(ObservableFlatMapCompletableCompletable.java:49)

    at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1592)

    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableObserveOn.subscribeActual(CompletableObserveOn.java:34)

    at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1592)

     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)

    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)

    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)

    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)


   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: do you use proguard?

Comment: Could you provide all code of UserAccountManager

Comment: @Sergey  Hello, I have added the code for the UserAccountManager

Comment: Where do you use `UserAccountManager#startUserSession()`?

Comment: Where startUserSession() is implemented?

Comment: @Sergey sorry, my mistake when editing. startSession is actually startUserSession. Thats all the code posted there. Sorry for the inconveninence

Comment: Are you using `Jack` or the new `desugar` toolchain?